# Data not saving

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis

It's a strange issue. i have developed web application using MVC & Entity Framework 6. when i run that application on local machine, data save smoothly. but when it connect to remote server & published on it remote server. Database also in remote server, data not saving. but it doesn't pop up any error to catch it. We have experienced like this way. using local source, change the connection string to the remote server database and debug it. when it doing data save smoothly. is it published error?

Expect yours help...

Comment: Without some sort of error its going to be hard for anyone to help you :( Are you sure you aren't surpressing or swallowing the error. Or the error is being sent back to the client but you arent handling it?

Comment: actually when we test it using sql server profiler it's stopped where write a record to table. data retrieving part is ok. yes we have handle the the error. but it doesn't throw to the UI. Actually we are in a huge problem now.